# The differences between using `val` and `def` for function definition in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I defined two functions(method) in Scala REPL:

```
scala> val b=(x:Int)=>x+1
b: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> def c(x:Int)=x+1
c: (x: Int)Int
```

And the usage:

```
scala> b(1)
res4: Int = 2

scala> c(1)
res5: Int = 2
```

While both definition works, it seems that `b` and `c` have different type.  And I was wondering whether there are some differences between them. Why doesn't Scala use the same type for `b` and `c`? Does anyone have ideas about this?

---

Not duplicate:

> This question is not a duplicate of the linked question. Even though
>   it asks about the difference between using def and val to define a
>   function, the code example makes it clear that the asker is confused
>   about the difference between methods and functions in Scala. The
>   example doesn't use a def to define a function at all. –  Aaron
>   Novstrup 7 hours ago

Comment: One of them would generate new instance of function for every call.

Comment: This question is _not_ a duplicate of the linked question. Even though it asks about the difference between using `def` and `val` to define a function, the code example makes it clear that the asker is confused about [the difference between methods and functions in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala). The example doesn't use a `def` to define a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `def` creates a method (in the case of the REPL it will create a method in some global invisible object), `val` instead will create an anonymous function and assign it to the symbol you specified.

When invoking those they are pretty much the same thing; when you pass them around there is a difference but Scala hides it from you by performing the ETA expansion transparently. As an example if you define this:

```
def isEven(i: Int): Boolean = i % 2 == 0
```

And then call

```
list.filter(isEven)
```

Scala is transforming that for you in a way that is similar to using the `val` way instead; take it as a pseudo-code as I don't know so well the scala internals but at at high level this is what happens:

```
list.filter((i: Int) => isEven(i))
```